# combining two selects

Tags: sql

I have two SELECTS which I combinedto make it work as one :

```
SELECT     dbo.doss.dosno, dbo.doss.dosnm, SUM(dbo.kbpres.uur) AS somuur, SUM(dbo.kbpres.minuut) AS somminuut, CAST(SUM(dbo.kbpres.uur) + SUM(dbo.kbpres.minuut) 
                  / 60 AS VARCHAR(4)) + 'u ' + CAST(SUM(dbo.kbpres.minuut) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)) + 'm' AS derivedColumn, SUM((dbo.kbpres.uur * 60 + dbo.kbpres.minuut) 
                  * dbo.kbpres.prijs) AS TotalCost, dbo.doss.behdr, NULL AS FACKOSTEN
FROM         dbo.kbpres INNER JOIN
                  dbo.doss ON dbo.kbpres.ino = dbo.doss.ino
WHERE     (dbo.doss.dosno = '93690')
GROUP BY dbo.doss.dosno, dbo.doss.behdr, dbo.doss.dosnm
UNION
SELECT     doss_1.dosno, doss_1.dosnm, NULL AS [somuur], NULL AS [somminuut], NULL AS    [derivedColumn], NULL AS [TotalCost], doss_1.behdr, SUM(kbpres_1.prijs) AS FACKOSTEN
FROM         dbo.kbpres AS kbpres_1 INNER JOIN
                  dbo.doss AS doss_1 ON kbpres_1.ino = doss_1.ino
WHERE     (doss_1.dosno = '93690') AND (kbpres_1.soort = 'K')
GROUP BY doss_1.dosno, doss_1.dosnm, doss_1.behdr,kbpres_1.soort
```

Seperately they result in one row. So now I made the UNION it result in two rows. But how can I make this result in 1 row (1 result) ?

Comment: You can't from what you describe.  Why do you want to make it one row? Is it for a report or a form UI?  Bring back the data and make it one row on the client side.

Comment: yes it i for some kind of report. to make it easy to test I use dosno='3690', but in the live all dosno are returned in a datagridview in a visual studio form , so it should be in the same row for each dosno. How would I best do it then ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a subquery like:

SELECT a, b, c, (SELECT d, e, f FROM b WHERE blah blah) FROM a WHERE blah blah GROUP by a.blah

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate by posting the two rows you're getting back, as well as the one row that you expect to get back?

It's no surprise that you're getting back two rows now, as the `UNION` will aggregate all rows from your selects that have distinct values.  (Note that if your two rows were the same, `UNION` would condense them to one, whereas `UNION ALL` would still return both.)

I think that you'll need to do something like

```
SELECT ... 
FROM
(  
    -- your query
) q
GROUP BY ...
```

but again, since your rows have distinct values, you will likely end up with the same result set.  I think posting the details I mentioned earlier will get you better answers.  It's possible that I'm missing what you're trying to do all together, but it's difficult to tell based on the details in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get rid of the union and do joins. You can join the same table many times as long as it has a unique alias. What I would recommend is that you do the from statement with the doss table then do the kbpres joins twice. Something like the following:

```
FROM dbo.doss
INNER JOIN dbo.kbpres ON dbo.doss.ino = dbo.kbpres.ino
INNER JOIN dbo.kbpres AS kbpres_1 ON dbo.doss.ino = dbo.AS kbpres_1.ino AND (kbpres_1.soort = 'K')
```